# simplehtmldom trigger click on element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to trigger a click on the following element, and then get the innertext of it.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="javascript:;" onClick="score(238953,this)">Show result</a>
```

After "onClick" has been triggered, it should look like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="javascript:;" onClick="score(238953,this)">1 : 2</a>
```

This is the code I've tried:

```
$winner = $this->data->find('.btn-sm', 0)->onclick->innertext;
```

I am trying to get the **1 : 2** from "innertext".
It is not working, and I don't know if it even does. But any help is appreciated.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server and generates the HTML page as text output. The response is send to the browser and rendered as a web page. Here the user clicks the element and the event happens. Here is no direct connection to the PHP. You will have to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: That's what I expected. So there is no smart solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using  `textContent()` and jQuery `on` event handler:

```
<?php

//php code

?>

<script>

    $('.btn-sm').on('click', function() {

        var txt = $(this).textContent();
    })

</script>
```

Comment: How do I put that inside PHP file?

Comment: using a `<script>` tag

Comment: Sure, but how do I then parse it into a PHP variable?

Comment: You wanna store the result into a php variable?

Comment: Yes, that's important.

Comment: @EmrikAhlström, in that case you have to use ajax and pass the value to a different php file using ajax